# Static and dynamic Items in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

My app contains a master/detail flow. If I click a ListViewItem a new Fragment is displayed in the detail flow whith its own menu items in the actionbar. I change them with:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.clear();
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.klasse, menu);
}
```

Default the items are displayed at the right side of the screen. Now I want some items which are allways there (not depending on the fragment) on the left side of the screen. So I want some static items on the left in the actionbar and some which can change dynamicly on the right side. How can i realize that?

Or in other words: One OptionMenu for the Activity where the items are static and on the left side and one OptionMenu for the Fragments which can change dynamicly but all in one ActionBar on the top of the Screen. The Event for the static items I want to handel in the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works like a charm for me with static Items on the left side of the ActionBar. See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667427/2047987

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to implement `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in your activity to have it add action items to the action bar, in addition to those being contributed by your fragments. You can use things like `android:orderInCategory` to control the sequencing. However, none of the action items will be "on the left side of the screen", as that is reserved for the home affordance, title, and navigation (e.g., drop-down list).